# Use rosconsole with argument of type double

Tags: ros, roscpp, rosconsole, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging#Log_Statements) does not state which argument type rosconsole takes. How do I get the double printed with `%d`, the conversion to int is obviously working but not right. mmh

```
double distance = 0.1;
int tmp1 = int(distance);
ROS_DEBUG_THROTTLE(1,"min:%d", tmp1);
```

In case I use type double it wount compile

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233365/use-rosconsole-with-argument-of-type-double/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The logging statements in C++ use printf-style formatting. For doubles, you should use the `%f` format specifier.

There are lots of good documents about the printf format types on the internet; for example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1